# where are standard libraries in Code Blocks?

Tags: c, codeblocks, libraries, standard-library

I want to read the code of the implementation of the functions of string.h; I found only the header file... what kind of extension have I to search? .dll or .o? and how can i read them, which program should I use?

Comment: `.dll`. and `.o` are binary files, they are not designed for you to read them. Why would you want that?

Comment: i want to read the implementation of function in libraries to understand better their work

Comment: Well then, `.o` is just a compiled C output, a stream of bytes. So it's rather impossible to read its contents in any presentable format. You can google most of the implementations of `string.h` very easily though, if you can't find them in the header file.

Answer (score 2):

Code::Blocks is an IDE. Hence you might what to check the source code from the Compiler it is using.

MinGW compilers collection is what I am using along with code blocks.
So check for source there.

Comment: what should I search? what kind of file? with whom extension?

Comment: checkout the cvs repo and explore.
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Official_CVS_Repository